# Python Twisted DatagramProtocol UDP Client Reconnect

Tags: python, networking, udp, twisted

Given that I have implemented a UDP Client in Twisted with the DatagramProtocol, and using it to communicate to a UDP Server, which at one point goes offline (due to a restart - so it does not change it's IP address), stopProtocol in my protocol is called, however the transport itself is set to None by Twisted.

How can I solve a simple reconnect in Twisted or re-initiate the transport?
I cannot connect again with udp according to the docs.

Given that in UDP the sender should be able to send packets even after the server is dead, and given that the protocol has it's own connection handling in the packets, I could reconnect the logical part entirely over the Packet layer, if the transport would not disappear.

I suppose running listenUDP again with a new protocol while the core is running won't work.

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
from twisted.internet import reactor


class UDPClientProtocol(DatagramProtocol):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
       self.host = host
       self.port = port

    def startProtocol(self):
       # Called when transport is connected
       self.transport.connect(self.host, self.port)
       self.transport.write('initiate protocol') # pseudo code.

    def stopProtocol(self):
       print "I have lost connection and self.transport is gone!"
       # wait some time and try to reconnect somehow?

 t = reactor.listenUDP(0, UDPClientProtocol('127.0.0.1', 12345))
 reactor.run()
```

Comment: Turn on logging so you can see if there is a bug in the protocol class that causes an unhandled exception to be raised somewhere.  Protocols that raise exceptions are disconnected from their transport.

Comment: I will try to look if there are any errors, the code is slightly complex now already, so I have to produce a simple example anyway, and I will provide more information then. as I was saying, the "stopProtocol" is called, so it is a DatagramProtocol.doStop coming from twisted itself, if the udp server i am connected to is shut down. Also forgot to mention, I do a self.transport.connect() in the startProtocol before the first write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting.  That sounds like something that shouldn't happen.  Is this due to a network interface restart or something?  What conditions reproduce this?

The simple answer to your question is probably "call `listenUDP` again, with 'self'", but I am curious what could cause this error to happen in the first place.

Comment: I researched myself, going deeper into twisted code. I will try the listenUDP, i wasnt sure if i can do that after reactor.run()...
I will look if I can make a slim example and test it. However, I did overwrite doStop in my protocol to test further, since transport is set to None there, and found out, that the socket itself is gone too.
It happens everytime the target server application shuts down for a restart.

Comment: calling listenUDP(0, self) did the trick, after refactoring the code to be able to do so. There were no exceptions raised by me, however, the disconnect happens as soon as the target server "hangs up", however it does it.

The used protocol was BattlEye, the Server is an Arma Server, i uploaded the protocol file to http://pastebin.com/kKNQk7ex.

Comment: note, that there is no network interface restart, simply an app restart on the server (of the server app - arma). the uploaded file does not contain the fix, obviously it would be calling listenUDP in my custom function networkError in a deferred.

Comment: It sounds like this might be producing an ICMP host unreachable notification when receiving a datagram from your application.  Do you have monitoring in place on your network where you can investigate what the "hang up" actually is?

Comment: if i would know how to do this, i would; however inside of my twisted app, i cannot, since i do not receive any data; twisted recognizes the closing socket seemingly internally (or layers below it) and closes my protocol, which might be on the ICMP level - which i am not that familiar with yet. if i would know how to set up a trace, i would - the only thing i cannot change obviously is the server executable; one thing i can rule out is the server setup itself (by hardware and os), because i have used it on several hosts with the same effect.

Comment: I would suggest giving http://www.wireshark.org/ a try (it may be a little hard to use, but it's a very useful tool)

Comment: @g4borg - by the way, I should say that I think it's clear to me at this point that you've discovered a bug in Twisted and we should work to fix it :).

Comment: I realized, I had not logged the Idling Packets (typo, rly sorry), and at this time it seems, the disconnect is only recognized at that point; so not really "passively" at the restart, but at the first packet going into nowhere. which again could be triggering the ICMP packet you mentioned, maybe through firewall or sth. (have not checked that yet). Of course the rest stays the same (the packet is sent, after that the protocol closes, further packets trigger an exception since the socket is gone)
Does not seem like a bug to me, if twisted recognizes the connection is gone :)

Comment: The thing is, it's UDP, so the connection is not really "gone", just temporarily unavailable.  It should report that to you in some way but it shouldn't be un-binding your port and closing your socket!

Comment: true. now i am very proud of myself finding a real bug. but at least, this matter is fixed (at least, atm. the error is quite easy to catch and the workaround works) thankyousomuch.

Answer (score 1):

I used following technique that I saw at [Twisted DNS source file](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-11.0.0/twisted/names/dns.py#L1752). It survives server disconnection and even network failures.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol, task
import time

class EchoClientDatagramProtocol(protocol.DatagramProtocol):
    def __init__(self, host, port, reactor):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self._reactor = reactor

    def startProtocol(self):
        self.transport.connect(self.host, self.port)

    def stopProtocol(self):
        #on disconnect
        self._reactor.listenUDP(0, self)

    def sendDatagram(self):
        datagram = ntp_packet
        try:
            self.transport.write(datagram, (self.host, self.port))
            print "{:0.6f}".format(time.time())
        except:
            pass

    def datagramReceived(self, datagram, host):
        pass
        #print 'Datagram received: ', repr(datagram)
        #self.sendDatagram()

def main():
    protocol = EchoClientDatagramProtocol('127.0.0.1', 8000, reactor)
    t = reactor.listenUDP(0, protocol)
    l = task.LoopingCall(protocol.sendDatagram)
    l.start(1.0) # call every second
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```